# Site failing to authenticate user

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth, vagrant, homestead

I can't seem to figure this out, I'm also a Laravel newbie - so maybe looking in the wrong place. I've set up a new site on my computer from a repo and everything compiles correctly, but I am unable to resolve an OAuth error. The site is a user dashboard and I need to be able to login to see the other pages.

When I open the site I see the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Failed to re-authenticate user
```

And when I attempt to login with my credentials I see:

```
VM38:1 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I looked at my Laravel logs and see the following message:

```
local.ERROR: Key path "file:///home/vagrant/code/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): Key path \"file:///home/vagrant/code/storage/oauth-private.key\" does not exist or is not readable at /home/vagrant/code/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php:45)
```

When I initially set up the site, I successfully ran:

```
composer install
php artisan migrate
```

and generated a new OAuth key with: `artisan passport:client --password`.

Unable to figure out how to resolve the token error.

Comment: Did you run `php artisan key:generate` after installation? If this is true, did you also run `php artisan passport:install`?

Comment: I've run `artisan passport:install`, and see my keys files generated, but get a `401 unauthorized` error when I attempt to login.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `php artisan passport:install` to generate your key files.

Comment: I ran this, and now I see files with my OAuth keys generated which I hadn't before. Unfortunately, I still get an error message when logging in, a different one though: `oauth/token 401 (Unauthorized)`.